# Where did the default GTK2 theme (raleigh) theme come from?

Tags: history, gtk, theme

Who made the theme?
When was the theme made? 
Was it made originally for a specific distro?
Does the theme have anything to do with the city of Raleigh?

Comment: What theme? Default where? What's `raleigh`?

Comment: It's the default gtk2 theme when there is no theme.

Answer (score 1):

Per the changelog in [`gtk-engines-0.12/raleigh`](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gtk-engines/0.12/):

```
Sat Feb 10 08:34:10 2001  Owen Taylor
.............................
    * started ChangeLog.
```

I don't think it was made for a specific distro, namely *Red Hat* (as Owen worked/works @ *Red Hat*).
It's a `gtk` theme as the `README` from the same package says:

> This is a theme engine that implements a cleaned up version of the
>   GTK+ default look - it is basically a cross between the GTK+ default
>   look and something more like Microsoft Windows, with a Macintosh style
>   option menu.

so basically available in any `gtk`-based *DE*.
As to your last question, I guess you'll have to ask Owen... but as *terdon* points out, *Red Hat* is based in Raleigh so that would explain the name.

Comment: Well, the RH headquarters [_are_ in Raleigh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat) so that would explain the name.